# Click a menu button to open a website

Tags: xcode, macos, web, hyperlink

[EDIT: wow this is still active? Hmmm.]

Sorry this is asked and answered in a another question, and i am not sure how this happened? Sorry this was my mistake

Answer (score 0):

NSWorkspace is responsible for that kinda stuff.

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:@"http://www.mylink.com"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this - but the easiest is using the `open` shell command:

`open http://www.google.com`

If you want to do this from C, C++ or Objective-C[++]:

`system("open http://www.google.com");`